# Change text in already existing local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

The app has local notifications in the notification manager. Is it possible to change text of already existing local notifications (e.g. the notification text had a mistake and I want to correct the existing messages)?

Comment: yes, you can retrieve the text of the uilocalnotification (with proper method) and after that you modify the text (but in notification center there will be no changes), this is only useful if you have to use the text of the notification within the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not possible to directly edit the notification, you may

1. Get the array of scheduled notifications
2. Create a mutable copy
3. Create a new notification based on the one you want to modify
4. Insert the notification
5. Remove the old notification
6. Set this new array as the list of scheduled notifications

You may of course combine 4.+5. by replacing the object.

Comment: thanks, it would work if I had to edit scheduled notifications, but I need to change the message in the notification manager. nevertheless, thanks for the detailed answer)

Comment: Oh, I obviously misunderstood your question. For already presented messages: there is no way to change them.

Answer (score 0):

NO. A notification in the notification manager can not be changed.